# Reading & Writing multiple HashMaps

Tags: java, input, stream, hashmap, output

I have two HashMaps

```
public static HashMap<String, Date> taskMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();
private HashMap<String,String> passMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and one method which is only able to read the first Map

```
private void readData() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("data/tasks.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        taskMap.putAll((HashMap)ois.readObject());
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to write both HashMaps in a single file and then be able to read both of them to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just write them both to the `ObjectOutputStream`, and read them both from the `ObjectInputStream`, in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the way you want to store them, object serialization serializes just one object, one approach would be to create a wrapper class that contains both maps, another way would be to change your serialization mechanism.

Comment: 'Object serialization serializes just one object' is nonsense. Java Object Serialization serializes as many objects as you like.

Comment: Nonetheless the approach would work. Especially the container class could be useful if storing more than just that at once.

Comment: @Zabuza Of course it will work, and that in itself is proof that the statement I quoted is incorrect.